# Passing Hashes to a Powershell function problem

Tags: windows, function, powershell

I must be missing something. i have to variables:
$var1 and $var2

```
$var1 | gm 
 TypeName: System.Collections.Hashtable
```

Each of them has IP and Port property, for example $var1[0].ip = '1.1.1.1'; $var1[0].ports = @(22,23,24)

Now I want to create a function that does some comparing between those 2 objects:

```
Function CompareData ($data1,$data2){
    $data1 | gm #this is just for me to test whats wrong
    write-host "first data $data1.ip" #just for me
    write-host "Second data $data2.ip" #just for me
    $str =''
    #check each ip in data2 if it exists in data1
    #if it exists, start checking for ports
    #if not exists do bla bla
    For ($i=0; $i -lt $data2.count; $i++){
        $ip = $data2[$i].ip
        for ($j=0; $j -lt $data1.count; $j++){
            if ($data1[$j].ip -eq $ip){
                $str += "$ip`r`n"
                $str += "Base ports: $data1[$i].ports`r`n"
                $str += "Current ports: $data2[$j].ports`r`n"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

the function isnt ready, what i do want to know is why im having a problem passing $var1 and $var2
Im doing this:

```
CompareData ($var1, $var2)
```

and it looks like only $var1 is passing while $var2 comes empty, also, if i do (inside function):

```
$data1 | gm
System.Object[] System.Object[].ip
```

meaning the function isnt getting the variables as i want. what am i missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use parentheses, PowerShell constructs an array with all the values in it, and uses that as the value for *one* parameter.

So, `CompareData ($var1, $var2)` is equivalent to `CompareData -data1 @($var1, $var2)` with no value specified for the `-data2` parameter.

If you use `CompareData -data1 $var1 -data2 $var2` as suggested by @dwillits you should get the result you expect.

Answer (score 1):

I've had problems with my functions when calling them with parenthesis.  Have you tried calling your function like so?

```
    CompareData -data1 $var1 -data2 $var2
```

Comment: Will do. Thanks very much

Comment: It turns out you were right and i learnt something new :)

Comment: Awesome!  I learned something new as well!  :)  Thanks to mclayton, I now know the why.  I'm glad it's working for you now.