# The first parameter contains all parameters

Tags: powershell

I am using PowerShell 5.1.18362.752 and I don't understand what happens here:

```
function test 
{
    param ( $str1, $str2)   

    Write-Host "1 in function : $str1"
    Write-Host "2 in function : $str2"
}

$var1 = "toto"
$var2 = "titi"

Write-Host "1 : $var1"
Write-Host "2 : $var2"

test($var1, $var2)
```

The Output:

```
PS C:\> c:\test.ps1
1 : toto
2 : titi
1 in function : toto titi
2 in function :
```

The arguments `$var1` and `$var2` are "put in" `$str1`, did I something wrong?

Comment: Duplicate(ish) of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63288033/passing-hashes-to-a-powershell-function-problem/63290029#63290029 - bottom line is you don't use brackets to surround parameters to cmdlets - PowerShell treats ```($var1, $var2)``` as an array and passes it to the first parameter of the function - i.e. it thinks you mean ```test -str1 @(var1, $var2)```. Use ```test -str1 $var1 -str2 -$var2``` or ```test $var1 $var2``` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

`test $var1  $var2`

or

`test -str1 $var1 -str2 $var2`

as you would use

`Get-ChildItem -Path $varx`